# Odd 'skip' function: error when running is double loops

Tags: c, algorithm, file, file-io, io

I am tasked with creating a function that does nothing but skip a line at the newline character and also it discards the rest of a line beyond the character array capacity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void skip(FILE *stream)
{
    char line[30];
    //while (fscanf(stream, "%*[^\n]")) {}
    while(fscanf(stream, "%s", line)) {
        if (strlen(line) > 30) {
            printf("invalid, str length: %lu", strlen(line));
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *stream;
    char line[30];
    int count = 0;
    stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while (fscanf(stream, "%s", line) != EOF) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
        skip(stream);
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    fclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program, it has a command line argument where it takes a file as an option, which refers to the input file, e.g. input.txt like this:

```
dog
dog
cow
milk
horse
shoe
rat
moose
milk
boat
goat
```

My current output is:

```
dog dog cow milk horse shoe rat moose milk boat goat
```

I want to the one word per line version as the output, like the input, as long as no lines are too long. The one line version is the bad output and the kind I have been getting recently.

I know this is probably such a typical question and I am able to print it with newline in a normal program but inside this function given the circumstances, it is a pretty odd thing.

Comment: So the one-word-per-line version is the sample input and the one-line version is the desired output? What is the problem, what do want not to happen? Or what do you want to happen but does not? I.e. what is the question?

Comment: If `if (strlen(line) > 30)` is true on a `char line[30];` you are already in trouble, the exit then is too late.

Comment: This migth be helpful: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: I want to the one word per line version as the output as it is already the input. The one line version is the bad output and the kind I have been getting recently

Comment: Please clarify that inside your question.

Comment: Did you compile with strict warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall` at least?

Comment: Yes, it compiles.

Comment: With or without warnings?

Comment: Yes with warnings

Comment: You should only post code which does not trigger warnings, execpet if you ask about exactly those warnings. This is because warnings are helpful and ignoring them may subtly cause the problem you ask about. (Not in this case, but as a principle.)

Comment: You do not want to delete every second line, do you? Then don't read anything you want to keep within `skip()`.

Comment: By the way, I cannot see anything infinitly looping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

This allows to only read as many characters as you want:

> (optional) integer number (greater than zero) that specifies maximum
>   field width, that is, the maximum number of characters that the
>   function is allowed to consume when doing the conversion specified by
>   the current conversion specification. Note that %s and %[ may lead to
>   buffer overflow if the width is not provided.

Then this allows you to read but not store the rest of a line:

> (optional) assignment-suppressing character *. If this option is
>   present, the function does not assign the result of the conversion to
>   any receiving argument.

Then this allows you to read (ignoring, see above) everything not a newline:

> [set]  matches a non-empty sequence of character from set of
>   characters. If the first character of the set is ^, then all
>   characters not in the set are matched. If the set begins with ] or ^]
>   then the ] character is also included into the set. It is
>   implementation-defined whether the character - in the non-initial
>   position in the scanset may be indicating a range, as in [0-9]. If
>   width specifier is used, matches only up to width. Always stores a
>   null character in addition to the characters matched (so the **argument
>   array must have room for at least width+1 characters**)

E.g. replace your loop with this
(note the deleted call of unneeded `skip()`
 and that I intentionelly only read up to four characters, to demonstrate the effect):

```
while (fscanf(stream, "%4s%*[^\n]", line) != EOF) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", line);
    count++;
}
```

Make sure to read at least one character fewer than the size of the array you store the result in, because of the part I highlighted (bold).

Output:

```
dog
dog
cow
milk
hors
shoe
rat
moos
milk
boat
goat
11
```

If you need a `skip()` being used, you can define it as:

```
void skip(FILE *stream)
{
    fscanf(stream, "%*[^\n]");
}
```

and call like:

```
while (fscanf(stream, "%4s", line) != EOF) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", line);
    skip(stream);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: What does the star do?

Comment: The skip function must exist

Comment: The star is explained in the second quote, did you read that?

Comment: The purpose of the skip function is achieved by the integer in the format string (mostly). If you insist on having a skip function, then do the ignoring of the rest of the line in that function.

Comment: Do you need the skip function to know and print the length? Does it have to exit?

Comment: See my answer above to see where I am trying to go with this. skip's only functionality right now is to skip. I need it to know length but it will only print up to what it can hold and it will not exit.

Comment: Knowing the length of what is beyond allowed length is not part of the original question. Please make a separate question of that detail.